# Indesign: get rid of automatic change of pointer functionality in picture frames

Tags: adobe-indesign

In Adobe Indesign (newer versions, I think somewhere after Indesign CS3) there is annoying behaviour of the mouse pointer (black arrow) to move frames: When pointing somewhere close to the center of a picture frame, the pointer automatically takes on the functionality of the white arrow (move contents of a frame inside the frame, rather than the frame itself).

This change of behaviour is indicated through a faint double circle appearing in the center of the picture frame, like here:

[image]

I find this annyoing. I usually have to move frames on the paper, not content of frames inside the frames. With this functionality, I always have to pay attention where I click in the frame, and the natural thing is to click in its center, especially when frames are small (like for logos etc.)

Is there a way to switch off this unwanted behaviour of the pointer (black arrow)? So that I can move the frame whereever I click on it? As it was in Indesign CS3 and other versions?

(I am currently using Indesign CC, Version 13.1)

Answer (score 0):

It can be disabled/enabled via menu: `View` -> `Extras` -> `Hide Content Grabber`

[image]